# MySQL InnoDB: how to switch to Barracuda format?

Tags: mysql, innodb, innodb-barracuda

In new MySQL versions Barracuda file format was introduced. So I havew a few questions:

- Is it working only with file_per_table option?
- How to switch existing system to it (preferably the whole tablespace) other than by reimporting everything from mysqldump backup on empty server?

Comment: i'd say - if this data has any value to you; take a full mysqldump before proceeding no matter what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are better off doing the mysqldump and reimporting

[Take a Look at This File Format Issue](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=53654)
[Here is another issue](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=47167)
[Here is a more recent article from DatabaseJournal](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3926696/MySQL-InnoDB-File-Formats.htm)

Comment: FYI, those top two bulleted issues have since been fixed.

Comment: If you have an update please post a new answer to this question